# Excluding possible image locations

Tags: python, combinations

I need to place images so they are not on each other. I'm looking at matrix 3x3, so 9 places. Image is horizontal and it's taking 2 places. I tried this way (edited):

```
other_position = [e for e in range(9)]

def find_horizontal_position(avaiable_pos):
    myList = avaiable_pos
    print(avaiable_pos)
    try:
        possible_position = [0,1,3,4,6,7] # positions where image is not cut in half
        position = random.choice(possible_position)
        myList.remove(position)
        myList.remove(position + 1)
    except ValueError:
        return find_horizontal_position(avaiable_pos)
    return myList, position

for _ in range(2):
    other_position, position = find_horizontal_position(other_position)
    print(position)
```

Sometimes it generates output like this:

```
1
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
4
[3, 6, 7, 8]
```

First image is placed on position 1, so 1 and 2 is taken out. Second image is on position 4, but by the way it takes away 0... Maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your except clause, incorporate a return statement:

```
return   find_horizontal_position(avaiable_pos)
```

otherwise what happens is that even though the position you attempted to place your image in is invalid, you will still execute the return statement

```
return myList, position
```

which in your example has `position==0`. Note that your approach might not find a valid solution even if one exists, I would suggest looping over all pairs

```
(img1leftposition, imp2leftposition), img1leftposition != imp2leftposition
```

where img1leftposition and img2leftposition are in `possible_position` (plenty of ways to do this, simple one using

```
for pair in zip(possible_position, possible_position):
    ...
```

Comment: My solution with additional return statement is still buggy. Now it correctly separates two images, but once in a while takes away one additional spot - I edited my post.
Can you explain better your suggestion, give sample code? I don't know the number or rectangle images, it can be 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: 0 was removed because when position==1, the first remove is succesful, so the try-statement only fails until you get to         myList.remove(position + 1).

Comment: This is way I'm creating myList. It should take old variable (other position).

Comment: errata: meant to say "because when position==0"

Comment: Once again, I created new variable and I'm removing positions from it. It should call old variable if it fails to match.

Comment: If you want to avoid this issue, i would suggest the intersection of myList, mylistshifted=[x-1 for x in myList], and possible_position

Comment: Use intersection_set= set(myList) & set(mylistshifted) & set(possible_position) and random-choose a position from intersection set. If intersection_set is non-empty, then you will always get a valid position.